# RecyclerView-v7 classes.jar file is not found

Tags: android, sdk, material-design, android-recyclerview

I've started work on material design concept of RecyclerView for this am researched the topics and followed on that way as first am updated the versions as follows

Tools:
Android SDK Tools - 23.0.2
Android SDK Platform-tools - 20
Android SDK Build-tools - 22.0.1

Extras:
Android Support Repositry - 15
Android Support Library - 22.2

After am updated these files am enter into the sdk folder path to get the recyclerView-v7 classes.jar file but instead of that there the .arr file only present.

After further research on concept am add the executable .jar file of recyclerView-v7 in my project and once am extend the RecyclerView in adapter class am not able to create the ViewHolder class of RecyclerView inside the adapter class. Please guide me to create the material concept in AndroidStudio/Eclipse.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` add at the end of `dependencies`

```
compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0')
```

---

If for some reason you will want to find `jar` file on HDD, it will be default in:

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview\libs
```

---

This is how should looks `dependencies` block:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile('com.android.support:support-v4:+')
```

}

After adding this you **must** sync gradle.

Finally in your layouts you will be able to use `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

Note that you must have in `android` group in `build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

> Tools: Android SDK Tools - 23.0.2 Android SDK Platform-tools - 20

Android SDK Tools rev. 24.3.3 is available.

Android SDK Platform-tools rev. 22 is available.

Comment: After add this in dependency, is there no need to add jar files?

Comment: Yes. If your support library is above 21 then you need only add this in `dependencies` and then sync gradle. No need to move `jar`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot and one more thing if we are work in eclipse wat to do?

Comment: in project the build.gradle is present in 2 types as one for the project and another one is for Module according to this in which build.gradle the dependency has to be add?

Comment: yes am add it in that file and now am facing issue in xml file android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView this class is not found in xml code

Comment: am add the code as you mentioned and sync gradle but still am face the issue as follows    "The following classes could not be instantiated" - android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView(open class, show exception, clear cache)

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "design.com.recyclerdesignview"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:+')
}

Comment: Did you upgraded Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools to newest version using Android SDK Manager? If not, do this, Platform-tools must be at least 22, and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry am updated the tools version on that time itself but am not restarted studio instead of that am just try sync the gradle.Thanks for your guidence  thanks a lot.